# convert blob image and upload to storage/s3 folder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-s3

I'm migrating an old database to a new one using `Laravel 5.8`

The problem is that in the old database, files are stored as Blob type.

How can I convert those files and upload them to `Amazon S3` cloud storage bucket?

There are more than 10k users and I'm using a loop to upload but the BLOB is not converting, that is my issue any help will be appreciated

My Code

```
//loop start
$imageContent = 'ÿØÿàJFIFÿáExifII*......'; // LONGBLOB data

Storage::disk('my_disk')
        ->putFile('images/users/travel.jpg', $imageContent);
//loop end
```

if I use this method then it throws an error

> Call to a member function hashName() on string

I also tried with `file_get_contents` and `base64_decode` methods but i didn't figure it out

Comment: try my answer from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51198882/how-to-recieve-image-blob-data-by-cropper-js-in-laravel-controller/51199008#51199008

Comment: Good suggestion and upload is working fine but the image is going to be corrupt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `put` function instead of `putFile`

Try this

```
$imageContent = 'ÿØÿàJFIFÿáExifII*......'; // LONGBLOB data

Storage::disk('my_disk')
       ->put('images/users/travel.jpg', $imageContent)
```

For more information [Storage disk instances](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#obtaining-disk-instances)

Comment: That is the solution that I want. it is working fine :)